# Addressable gem is not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Gemfile I have:

```
gem 'addressable'
```

In search_controller.rb:

```
uri = Addressable::URI.new
uri.query_values = {:q => query}
```

I get this error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant SearchController::Addressable):
```

If I put

```
require 'addressable/uri'
```

on top of my controller, it works!!. I have already done "sudo bundle install" and it shows addressable is installed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at addressable gem source I see it has no `lib/addressable.rb` which is default file which rubygems or bundler require when loading required gem. So it looks like it is designed this way on purpose - to make you explicitly require only the libraries you need.

Comment: +1 The correct `require` statement for Addressable::URI is `require 'addressable/uri'`.

Comment: I wrote Addressable. @khustochka is correct, the intention was to require only the portion of the library needed. In particular, most people do not need the template functionality.